# Can't see any tables in SQLite DB from NextJS API route

Tags: sqlite, next.js

I'm creating a SQLite DB using node via

```
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();

const db = new sqlite3.Database(
    './database.db',
    sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE,
);

db.serialize(() => {
    db.run('CREATE TABLE tables (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY)', (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
    db.run('CREATE TABLE seats (id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, `table` TEXT, name TEXT)', (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Then in NextJS, I just try to retrieve the values in `tables` via

```
import sqlite3 from "sqlite3";
import { open, Database } from "sqlite";

let db: Database;

export async function GET(req: Request) {
    if (!db) {
        db = await open({
            filename: "../database.db",
            driver: sqlite3.Database,
        });
    }

    const tables = await db.all("SELECT * FROM `tables`");

    return new Response(JSON.stringify(tables), {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        status: 200,
    });
}
```

But I get an error that `tables` doesn't exist. If I run

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_schema WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name
```

I get back an empty response. Growing on weird, if I check the database via VSCode's SQLite viewer, it shows me 2 tables, and the structures I setup, but Beekeeper Studio gives an error trying to access the database.